# Problem with variables in use clause of preg_replace_callback function in PHP

Tags: php

I encountered strange behavior in callback function. Following is the code that should replace every letter of a string to it's serial number while creating the map of replacements.

```php
$i = 2;
$map = [];
$token = preg_replace_callback(
  '~\w~',
  function($matches) use($map, $i) {
    $i += 1;
    $map[$i] = $matches[0];
    print "$i ";
    return $i;
  },
  '$token'
);
print_r($map);
print "\n$token";
```

Weirdly it prints

```
3 3 3 3 3 Array
(
)

$33333
```

i.e. $i value is taken but it's changing not used in next callback calls. What's going on here? And how to fix it?

Sandbox below
https://onlinephp.io/c/a4b1c0

Comment: Concerning `$i` use `&$i` in the `use` parameter list (by reference).  Recommend posting your expected results as well.  This one change produces: `3 4 5 6 7 Array
(
)

$34567`

Comment: Do you need the value of `$i` oustide of the callback function? Also, what is your PHP version?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte There's no PHP version dependency here; closures in PHP have always captured by-value, and always supported the `&` modifier to capture by-reference instead.

Comment: @IMSoP: Cool! Please could you share a link about this interesting point about closures behavior?

Comment: @IMSoP: I was joking!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You asked for a PHP version on a question where the version wouldn't change the answer at all, so I pointed that out. If you were trying to make a sarcastic response, I don't know what the intended message was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `use` parameters by reference, as in :

```
$token = preg_replace_callback('~\w~', function ($matches) use (&$map, &$i) {
        $i += 1;
        $map[$i] = $matches[0];
        print "$i ";
        
        return $i;
    }, '$token');
```

Produces:

```
3 4 5 6 7 Array
(
[3] => t
[4] => o
[5] => k
[6] => e
[7] => n
)

$34567
```

You'd have to clarify your question to determine if this is what is desired besides the obvious value-vs-reference issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default variable capture in PHP is *by value only* - when the closure is created, the current value of each variable in the `use` list is examined, and assigned to a local variable with the same name inside the closure. Assigning to the local variable inside the closure does not write back to the variable which was originally captured, and every time you execute the closure, the captured variables start with their originally captured value.

This is different from some other languages, like JavaScript, where closures carry writeable references to their captured variables. Capturing by value is generally easier to understand, for instance if you want to create a list of closures in a loop:

```
$callbacks = [];
foreach ( [1,3,5,7,9] as $number ) {
    $callbacks[] = function() use ($number) { return $number; };
}
```

If `$number` was captured by reference, all five closures would end up identical, all referring to the same variable; because it's captured by value, you get five different closures, each with a different value of `$number`.

In cases where you *do* want a reference, you can use the `&` modifier in the `use` list:

```
function($matches) use(&$map, &$i) {
   // ...
}
```

Now, the local name `$map` inside the closure refers to *the same variable* as the name `$map` outside it - any modification to one will be visible in the other.

This is similar to the difference between `$myMap = $yourMap` (assignment by value) and `$myMap =& $yourMap` (linking two variables as references).

(Note that, in all the above cases, the "value" of an object is a pointer to something mutable - so if `$map` was an object rather than array, calling `$map->setSomething(42)` would modify the same object that was visible inside and outside the closure. This is not the same as capturing or assigning by reference.)